# Принцип работы с room android

Tags: android, база-данных, listview, android-room

Я делаю приложение для андроида, в котором будет реализовано работу с бд как часть всего приложения. В данной программе есть активити на которое отвечает за результаты пользователя которые он получил в процессе работы с приложением, и вот я пытаюсь сделать что-то на подобии истории изменений этих самых результатов, то есть например пользователь получил какие-то результаты дальше он нажал на кнопку и эти результаты перекинулись в бд, которая будет реализована при помощи room, но вот вопрос как сделать так что-бы можно было на одном активити нажимать на кнопку а на другом можно было-бы посмотреть эту самую историю изменений. Я просто не знаю как еще сформулировать вопрос, но принцип такой что нужно из одного активити перекидывать данные на другое где будет адаптер бд или что-то типа такого. Если кто знает чем мне помочь или что посоветовать то буду очень благодарен, так как я пока изучал работу с room и в примере было только одно активити, а вот как работать с двумя я не представляю.

Comment: Не нужно ничего перекидывать между активити. Каждая активити работает напрямую с БД. Одна пишет в базу, другая читает из базы. Это как вы на сайте сейчас комментариями обмениваетесь, вы же не ломаете себе голову, как перекинуть свой комментарий на мой компьютер. Вы отправляете его на сервер, я читаю комментарии с сервера. Никто из нас ничего не знает о компьютерах другого, где он, что он, включен ли он вообще ..  Как то так.

Comment: Добавьте в метод обработки нажатия кнопки лог с нужной информацией, который потом и отобразите во втором активити.